# xml size is exceed capacity of MySQL "extractvalue" function , how can I solve this?

Tags: mysql, xml, extract, bigdata

I am coming to the end here. My XML (data) is too big for extractvalue function to handle.

when "data" length is around 10k it works find, but when it exceed 30k then it gave me null

```
 EXTRACTVALUE(data,'/a/b') as var1
```

Can any one recommend me something to get around this in mysql ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you’re running into is a bug with MySQL. The XML that you’re trying to parse is most likely too long. I’m pretty sure it’s related to this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62429. To get around this bug, you can just extract the portion of the XML that you’re trying to navigate or just use another method to extract the value that you're looking for. Anyways, you can see the answer that I posted to this question to see how the issue was resolved there. [ExtractValue with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395829/extractvalue-with-mysql)